# Using `<NuxtLink>` causes my app to crash outside of localhost. How do I fix this issue in Nuxt.js?

Tags: vue.js, routes, deployment, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

I am experiencing an issue with my Nuxt.js application where it crashes whenever I use the `<NuxtLink>` component outside of the localhost environment. The application works perfectly fine when running locally, but as soon as I deploy it to a remote server or access it from a different domain, it encounters crashes.

To temporarily fix the issue, I replaced the `<NuxtLink>` components with `<a>` tags as a workaround. This allowed me to avoid the application crashes when accessing it outside of the localhost environment. However, this solution is not ideal since it bypasses the benefits provided by `<NuxtLink>`.

In addition to that, I also attempted to use `router.push` instead of `<NuxtLink>` components. I expected that using programmatic navigation with `router.push` would help resolve the issue. However, this approach resulted in the same problem—my code works fine with `<NuxtLink>` components in the local development environment, but fails when deployed on Vercel.

Despite trying various alternatives, such as manually handling navigation using router.push or using `<a>` tags, the issue persists when using `<NuxtLink>` components outside of the localhost environment.

I'm seeking a solution that allows me to use `<NuxtLink>` components as intended in SSR mode and prevents the application crashes when deployed on Vercel or accessed from a different domain. Any guidance or insights to resolve this problem would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!